# Haskell. How can I test a BTree in GHCi?

Tags: haskell

I have this Code
Definition from a binarytree

```
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

And definition of function size

```
size' :: BTree a -> Integer
size' Empty = 0
size' (Node _ l r) = size' l + size' r + 1
```

How I understand, I have empty tree or a tree with a Node and two children.
Is it correct?

```
Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
```

according to this definition, cann I have only one Node?

I'm testing this so

```
size' (BTree 2 (Node 3 empty) (Node 6 empty)) 
size' (BTree 5 (Node 3 empty) (Node 8 empty) empty)
size' (BTree 'A' (Node 'B' empty) (Node 'C' empty))
size' (Node 5 (BTree 3 empty) (BTree 8 empty) empty)
size' (Node 5 (BTree 3 empty) (BTree 8 empty))
```

But all these causes errors

Comment: Note the difference between `empty` and `Empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition says that there are two ways to make a `BTree a`:

1. As `Empty`
2. As `Node x y z` where `x` has type `a`, and `y` and `z` have type `BTree a`.

So some examples of `BTree Int` would be:

1. `Empty`
2. `Node 0 Empty Empty`
3. `Node 1 (Node 2 Empty Empty) Empty`